# Entity Framework and table without inserts or updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do you tell the Entity Framework that it is not supposed to create or modify rows in a table, while allowing it to read the data and create an object for it?

The only thing that I see that might do that is to set all columns as Computed, is that the right approach?

Comment: Probably the right option here is to wrap your Data Access in a repository object of some sort that can be made read-only. Handling data modification permissions is not really a role for EF.

Comment: Agree with @NickBailey. Either something like he suggests, or protect the database from updates at the database level itself, based on the permissions of the user that EF is connecting as.

Comment: Do you also want the entity to be immutable as class?

Comment: @GertArnold: yes, this data is view only as far as the app is concerned.

Comment: You can make the property setters private. EF can deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways, one way may be to override your savechanges and catch any attempts to save the entity

```
var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IDoNotSave>();

        if (changeSet != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
        }
```

Then just add the IDoNotSave interface to the entities you don't want to be changed. The above should catch attempts to Add, Delete or Modify. Any attempt to save changes to the entity should silently fail. Of course, you could throw an error instead of change the EntityState to Unchanged if that's the requirement.